# For Vim, and specifically coc.vim, is it idomatic to use `gd` to open a link?

Tags: plugin-coc

I use coc.vim heavily and am a big fan of `gD` to go to a definition.

Two questions:

- Is `gD` idiomatic vim, or more a coc thing?
- When I have links in markdown files to URLs, it feels natural to me to use `gD` to want to open them (I think this is like the "Command + Click" in a graphical editor - but is there a more 'vim' way that keeps this flow?

Example case is I have a README file that has links to some further docs, I'm just curious to open the links without leaving the keyboard. I could yank the contents of the link, use `!open C^R` but it feels less intuitive.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, both the native `:help gd` and the native `:help gD` are "go to *declaration*", not "go to *definition*". The difference may or may not be meaningful to you but that is a first level of removal from the original commands.

Then you have the fact that both commands are constrained to the current buffer: `gd` is local to the current "block" (whatever that means) and `gD` covers the whole buffer. Jumping to another file is a second level of removal.

Then you have a third level of removal: opening the filename or URL under the cursor has nothing to do with the original "go to declaration" and is covered "natively" by separate commands: `:help gf` for files and `:help gx` for URLs.

The last level of removal is reached by lumping together unrelated functionalities into a single command, which goes against Vim's whole design.

Now, users and plugin developers are 100% free to override whatever command they want and deviate however they want from the core model but, IMO, that is going a little bit too far.

Anecdotally, I interacted a few times with CoC users who were super confused about `gd`. Some copied the example config from the `README.md` without even reading it and wondered why `gd` suddenly changed. Some only knew about CoC's `gd` and had no idea a built-in `gd` existed, which led to very frustrating discussions where the two parties talked about different things. Etc. There *is* a cost to that, that plugin authors often brush off because they are not the ones providing support for their own plugins.

Comment: Thank-you this is perfect - I will make `gf` and `gx` part of my day to day routine, as these are built in. This is really what I was looking for - the more pure vim way of handling this, avoiding plugins. Really appreciate the quick answer @romanl